# React-how to reset a form textarea

Tags: reactjs, forms

I want to reset the text area after click the submit button in react.
I can reset the state to the default value, however the text area won't clear.
Any idea?

here is my code:

```
 class Setting extends Component { 
  constructor(){
        this.state ={
           input: null
        }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  } 

   handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    //here is some logic to for handling input
    // .....
    event.preventDefault();
    // here I want to reset the textarea content once the logic is done
    this.restInput(); 
  }

  restInput= () => {
    this.setState({
        input :null
     })
  }

     render() {
      return (
        <form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <textarea value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
       )
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `null` to empty string and it'll work fine

```
restInput= () => {
    this.setState({
        input :""
     })
  }
```